# After clone/fork/vfork, parent and child processes have different return addresses

Tags: linux, centos, fork, system-calls, callstack

I work on centos 6.6, and want to add a `post-clone` hook for `clone`. I have changed the `syscall_table[__NR_clone]` to my function, where I change the return address on the stack to my `post-clone` function, and then make it jump to the actual `clone` syscall so that after the actual syscall, the program will return back to my `post-clone` function. Since I change the return address on the stack before the actual `clone` occurs, both parent and child processes are supposed to have the same return address. However, only the parent process returns back to my `post-clone`, while child process returns to the actual return address. Hope someone could help me figure out why it behave like this.

Comment: This is very interesting toipic, would you mind adding some code snippets?

Comment: @tlwhitec, sorry I don't have the code anymore. But it is just using the basic system call interception technique, which is changing the pointer of a syscall in the system call table to a function defined in a linux kernel module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out why the parent process and child process have different return addresses after `clone/fork/vfork`. The system call `clone` will invoke `copy_process()` in `kernel/fork.c`. The `copy_process()` will duplicate the `current` task structure to a variable `p`. Then `p` is passed to `copy_thread()`, where the instruction pointer (ip) of `p` is assigned by `ret_from_fork`, which is a assembly function in `entry.S` (or `entry_32.S` or `entry_64.S`). The 64 bits version varies a little bit but has the same idea.

The child process's ip is changed to `ret_from_fork`, while the parent process's ip remains the same. Therefore, after the system call `clone/fork/vfork`, parent and child processes will have different return addresses.